# CRC calculation over 26 bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, crc

I'm implementing simple protocol and I need to calculate CRC from following structure:

```
type    (1 byte, unsigned)
address (1 byte, unsigned)
dataID  (4 bytes, unsigned, little-endian)
data    (4 bytes, unsigned, little-endian)
data    (4 bytes, unsigned, little-endian)
data    (4 bytes, unsigned, little-endian)
data    (4 bytes, unsigned, little-endian)
data    (4 bytes, unsigned, little-endian)
-----------------
=       (26 bytes)
```

You can imagine it as simple JavaScript object:

```
var message = {
  type:    0x11,
  address: 0x01,
  dataID:  0xFFFFFFFF,
  data: [
    0xFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFF,
    0xFFFFFFFF
  ]
}
```

From this object I need to calculate CRC. Unfortunately, in manual is only `CRC calculation includes Message type, Slave Address Data-ID's and data values. CRC calculation is performed over 26 bytes.` so I'm not sure what should I do.

CRC is calculated using CRC16-CCIT function. So I downloaded [crc package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crc) from NPM which has this function already implemented.

It would be great if you post me code, because I have no idea what to do (you can use undeclared `crc` function which is equivalent to [this](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-crc/blob/master/src/crc16_ccitt.coffee)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
var crc16ccitt = require('crc').crc16ccitt;

function checksum(message) {
  var buf = new Buffer(26);
  buf.writeUInt8(message.type,      0);
  buf.writeUInt8(message.address,   1);
  buf.writeUInt32LE(message.dataID, 2);
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    buf.writeUInt32LE(message.data[i], 6 + i * 4);
  }
  return crc16ccitt(buf);
}
```

Comment: I added the missing informations. However it seems, it works well :). Thank you.